# Is there a systematic way of dealing with functions without a well defined limit approaching infinity (such as $\sin(x)$) as part of a limit problem?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}\sin{x} $, by the product rule of limits, we can split this up as: $(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x})(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sin{x})$, but while $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} = 0$, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sin{x}$ isn't well defined.

Intuition says that since $\sin x$ just fluctuates around zero, multiplying it by another function shouldn't change the limit as $x \to \infty$, and I was able to show formally that $(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x})(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sin{x}) = 0$ by using the taylor series decomposition of $\sin x$, breaking up the limit across terms, and applying iterated L'Hôpital rules, but is there a better (systematic) way of dealing with limits of products like this, where one of the limits (like $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sin{x}$) isn't well defined?

Comment: More generally, if $\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) = 0$ and $b(x)$ is bounded then $\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) b(x) = 0$.  Still more generally, if $|a(x)| \le A(x)$ and $|b(x)| \le B(x)$ for $x$ sufficiently large, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} A(x) B(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) b(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the squeeze theorem.

$$-e^{-x}\le e^{-x}\sin x\le e^{-x}$$.

Answer (score 1):

The product rule only applies if both limits exist and are finite, or at least one limit is not $0$ or one limit is not $\pm \infty$. If one limit doesn't exist, and you don't know anything else, then you can't say anything. For example $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} \cdot (e^{x^2}\sin x)$ doesn't exist. Yet your limit does exist. Like a comment suggested, in situations like yours you should appeal to something like boundedness of one of the terms, in the case that the limit of that term doesn't exist. This will allow you to show some limits are $\pm \infty$ if one limit is infinite and the other term is eventually bounded away from $0$ either positive or negative, and also that the limit is $0$ if one term is bounded and the limit of the other term is $0$.